# Multiprocessing function does not update the dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-multiprocessing

I have a dataframe with distance and I want to check these distance and apply some functions depending on the dstances values, I am trying to do it using multiprocessing, I created a dataframe with the same size of the original data frame but it has all values of zeros as follows:

```
df_final=pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(len(df)), columns=df.columns.tolist())
```

then I wrote the `generate` function which is to be called by multiprocessing as follows:

```
def generate(df_plus_id):
  #df = df_plus_id[0]
  #df_final =  df_plus_id[1]
  print("in dunc")
  print(df_final['NN_x1'].values.tolist()[0])
  for i in Regions:
    for j in range(df.shape[0]):
    
      #for k in range(i+"_Edges_Count"):
        edge_count=df[i+"_Edges_Count"].iloc[j]
        new_edge_count=df[i+"_Edges_Count"].iloc[j]
        #print("edge count is",str(edge_count))
        for k in range(1,edge_count+1):
          #print("k is",str(k))
          if (df[i+"_D"+str(k)].iloc[j]<=1.4):
            df_final[i+"_D"+str(k)].iloc[j]=df[i+"_D"+str(k)].iloc[j]
            print("in if")



            
          





          else:
            #print("in else")
            #print(df[i+"_D"+str(k)].iloc[j])
            #df_final[i+"_D"+str(k)].iloc[j]=0


            new_edge_count=k-1
            break

          
        for c in range(1,new_edge_count+1):
            #print("new edges count",str(new_edge_count))
            #print("c",str(c))
            #print("i",str(i))

            for feature in Features:
                #print("feature is",str(feature))
                #print("j is",str(j))
                df_final[i+feature+str(c)].iloc[j]=df[i+feature+str(c)].iloc[j]
                #print("loc is",str(df_final[[i+feature+str(c)]].iloc[j]))
            


            
        df_final[i+"_Edges_Count"].iloc[j]=new_edge_count
        if df_plus_id[2] == 0:
         df_final.to_csv('temporary_saved_files/' + str(df_plus_id[2]) + '.csv', index=False)
        else:
         df_final.to_csv('temporary_saved_files/' + str(df_plus_id[2]) + '.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

and the code in the main which calls the generate function is:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import math
number_of_CPU = "Max"
if  type(number_of_CPU) == int and number_of_CPU < mp.cpu_count() and number_of_CPU > 0 :
    processes = number_of_CPU
else:
    processes = mp.cpu_count()

# if number of processess > number of lines in df, make processses= number of lines.
if processes > df.shape[0]:
    processes = df.shape[0]
print('Generating the new training data using %s'%str(processes)+ ' processes.')
# Determine chunk size, which is the number of lines per processes
list_of_dfs = []
chunk_size = int(math.ceil(df.shape[0] / processes))
start = 0
end = chunk_size

# Divide the dataframe into chunks
for i in range(processes):

    if start >= df.shape[0]:
        # The ceiling could make a special case where the number of chunks < number of processses
        # Which will produce empty dataframe per process.
        # Ex 4 processes and 6 rows.
        break
    list_of_dfs.append([df.iloc[start:end, :],df_final.iloc[start:end, :],i])
    start = end
    end = end + chunk_size


processes = len(list_of_dfs)
# Make temporary directory for intermediate results

os.mkdir('temporary_saved_files')

with mp.Pool(processes) as pool:  # or whatever your hardware can support
    pool.map(generate, list_of_dfs)
# command = 'cat temporary_saved_files/*.csv  >'+saving_directory
# print(command)
os.popen('cat temporary_saved_files/*.csv  >' + './sample.csv').read()
print("done concat")
os.popen('rm -r temporary_saved_files').read()
```

However, df_final is still all zeros even after calling the generate function I don't know why? despite the fact that when I apply the lines in generate function sequentially without multiprocessing the df_final have the expected values. Any ideas why generate function does not write to df_final?

Comment: I didn't see the code which can pass `df_final` to other processes. So I guess you didn't do it. When you use `multiprocess` ,you have many processes.They don't  share any data unless you do something to help.They just modify their own `df_final` so the `df_final` on main process is never changed.

Comment: thank you for your comment, actually in my real code I was trying to write df_final, I write df_final of each process into csv file in temporary folder than I concatenate them in the end. However, I still have zeros in the final concatenated csv file

Comment: Have you tried using [Dask](https://dask.org/)?

Comment: No, but why? I used to do it using mp but I don't know why it is not working this time?